# change all columns conditional on other column

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(0,1,0,0,1), 
b= c(0,0,0,1,0), 
SL = c(1,0,1,0,0))

df2 = data.frame(a = c(NA,1,NA,0,1), 
b= c(NA,0,NA,1,0), 
SL = c(NA,0,NA,0,0))
```

Now, I would like to change all values in a row to NA if SL == 1, like in df2. I tried with dplyr --> mutate(), across(), mutate_all but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
         mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(SL != 1 ~ SL)))
df
#   a  b SL
#1 NA NA NA
#2  0  0  0
#3 NA NA NA
#4  0  0  0
#5  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `%in%`.

```
df[df$SL %in% 1, ] <- NA
df
#    a  b SL
# 1 NA NA NA
# 2  1  0  0
# 3 NA NA NA
# 4  0  1  0
# 5  1  0  0
```